# Where do questions about customizing Chrome OS into a development machine belong?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, google-chrome

Where do I ask the following question?

> Is there a way to change the look of crosh (Chrome Shell)? I would
>   like to reduce the font sizes and change the default font to something
>   smaller (monospaced font) and possibly transparency in the background.
>   I am using the Samsung ARM Chromebook with Chrome 26 in developer
>   mode.

Comment: Have you considered looking through all of the available sites first?

Comment: Chromebook questions should be on-topic for [su]. To wit: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chromebook

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question would be [on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) on [Super User](https://superuser.com). It currently has 214 questions tagged [`chromebook`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chromebook) and 221 questions tagged [`google-chrome-os`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-os).

Your problem is not directly related to programming (which would be off-topic on Super User) but it’s even less related to it than [questions on scripts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/script) which are accepted, so Super User should be preferred to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

There seems to be no Stack Exchange site more focused on Chrome OS as of now.

Comment: 5 years ago when I asked the question, the questions on Stack Exchange didn't go into the level of detail I was looking for.  But thanks for the pointers to tags, I hope it will help others.  There's also subreddits like r/chromeos and r/chromebook which are very active communities these days.

Comment: FYI stackexchange needs a chromebook only website IMO. it doesn't tho. so the best i found is reddit for chromebook. specifically there is a subreddit for crostini that is really useful/good.

Comment: Seems there's more question on SO tagged chromebook than on SU these days: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chromebook https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chromebook but they tend to be more like "cannot find libc.so.6" or kind of lower level questions, so yeah I'd say prefer SU.